# grails project does not appear to be part of a Grails application

Tags: grails-2.0

After migrating from my old Macbook Pro to my new one, I find that my project will no longer run. Grails keeps giving me a "Error /Users/Michael/{proj}/{proj} does not appear to be part of a Grails application". Refresh dependencies does seem to run successfully.

I have verified the following:

- there exists a folder grails-app in the project folder at the same location as on the old machine.
- I did run a grails clean followed by a grails upgrade to 2.0.4

The one thing it could be is that the user directory name has changed between the two machines, but I do not see the old user directory name in either .project or application.properties or in any settings.

Comment: check BuildConfig.groovy to see if the paths seem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oops, saw that I had left this question unanswered.

The answer was to erase everything and rebuild from github. When in doubt, nuke it until it glows....

Answer (score 15):

I solved this by deleting `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches\<project>.launch`.  It had cached the old absolute path.

Answer (score 6):

Open the command line from within STS and executed a "run-app". There is sometime a problem with he workspace caches.

Comment: this worked for me, after trying out what user1901966 suggested

Answer (score 0):

[Armand's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13911294/277861) above was the simplest solution - thanks Armand

This has been my experience - when working with the Grails in the IDE - in certain cases it's better to use the command line to issue grails commands (this was a good reminder)

Related to this, it seems better to run-app from cmd line as well (as opposed to using the IDE Project->Run As), since you can just stop the server easily with ctrl-c